# A Matrix Chain Multiplication algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to adapt an established dynamic programming Matrix Chain Multiplication algorithm to compare Javascript's performance to other languages.

**This is the Java version found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) from which I am adapting to Javascript:**

```
void matrixChainOrder(int[] p) {
    int n = p.length - 1;
    m = new int[n][n];
    s = new int[n][n];

    for (int L = 1; L < n; L++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - L; i++) {
            int j = i + L;
            m[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
                int q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i]*p[k+1]*p[j+1];
                if (q < m[i][j]) {
                    m[i][j] = q;
                    s[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the version I am adapting and it is the same as far as I can see, but the console logs the following error message: `TypeError: m[(k + 1)] is undefined`**

```js
var matrixChainOrder = function(p) {
    var n = p.length - 1;
    var m = [[,]];
    var s = [[,]];
    for (var L = 1; L < n; L++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < n - L; i++) {
            var j = i + L;
            m[i][j] = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
            for (var k = i; k < j; k++) {
                var q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i]*p[k+1]*p[j+1];
                if (q < m[i][j]) {
                    m[i][j] = q;
                    s[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var array = [15, 12, 16, 17, 19];
var d = new Date();
var start = d.getMilliseconds();
matrixChainOrder(array);
var end = d.getMilliseconds();
console.log(end - start);
```

I don't understand why a TypeError is being thrown... hoping someone else can spot the problem and help me out.

Comment: Your first issue is `[[,]]`, though it's technically valid syntax that doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Indeed the `[[,]]` is the first place I struggled with. Are you able to expand on that? This is how I came to believe it worked in that way - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/xg5mb1aa/)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals) for more information about them. Note that there is no direct multi-dimensional array support in JavaScript, only jagged arrays.